# Unregistering default Django apps from admin breaks tests

Tags: django, nose, django-testing, mezzanine

In one of my apps/admin.py I have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.redirects.models import Redirect

from mezzanine.generic.models import ThreadedComment
from mezzanine.conf.models import Setting

admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.unregister(Redirect)
admin.site.unregister(ThreadedComment)
admin.site.unregister(Setting)
```

This causes them to be removed from the admin like I want, and the application works fine.
However, when I run my tests via nose, I get this error `raise NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)
NotRegistered: The model Site is not registered` Which I assume is because it is trying to unregister something which is already unregistered. This is an example of a test that is failing:

```
class TestRegistration(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        email = ConfirmedEmail(email='test.com',company='Test Industries')
        email.save()

    def test_landing(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Why are you unregistering anything at all? I usually won't need to unregister unless we're overriding the default admin, something like admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)